# Setting a variable in a recursive JQuery/Javascript self-executing function (polling)

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, long-polling, self-executing-function

I need to set a variable (*tick)* with an initial value in a recursive self-executing JQuery script. When I try and run the script below obviously *tick* is going to revert back to 0 rather than the value the JSON object is returned with.

```
    (function poll(){
        var tick = 0;
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "/client-polling/" + tick,
                success: function(data) {
                    $( "#messagestack" ).append(data[2]);
                    tick = data[0]
                },
                dataType: "json",
                complete: poll
            });
        }, 10000);
    })();
```

Also for some reason when I have *tick* declared the function waits the entire 10 seconds before polling the first time. If I try to declare *tick* outside of the function all other scripts on the page freeze up.

Where do I declare tick so the first time the page is called it's set to 0 and then takes the value from the returned JSON object?

**Update:** Well it took most of the Eloquent Javascript book and 7 Douglas Crockford videos to figure out what the problem was and I had failed to realise that Javascript is single-threaded. I've read through so much of other peoples coding it had not really occurred to me that usually their scripts run through once and go on to the next. My 'event-loop' was stopping other scripts from running, and yes, on its own the function should have the variable on the outside.

I finally ended up using iFrames (non-public, single interface application so security not a concern) just to get it running and now looking at web workers for future builds. Thanks for the answers so far.

Comment: The prob is the complete callback, when your ajax completed, poll will be called again, so the script `var tick=0` will be called again. Trying move the tick outside does not work? What does the console say? Is there any error?

Comment: I would use a setInterval on the ajax call instead, so you don't overwrite your poll variable. And you'll have to call the function yourself the first time, if you don't want it to wait for 10 sec the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't just set a variable outside the function?

```
var tick = 0;
(function poll(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/client-polling/" + tick,
            success: function(data) {
                $( "#messagestack" ).append(data[2]);
                tick = data[0]
            },
            dataType: "json",
            complete: poll
        });
    }, 10000);
})();
```

Comment: For some reason the polling stops in both this script and a second polling script (no tick variable needed) on the same page when the variable is declared on the outside. I'm a Javascript noob and just started on the Eloquent Javascript book but I needed this script working sooner than I will get the book finished.:)

Comment: Well, maybe you should try setInterval function instead?

Comment: Yes, this did work for me. I had made a mistake with the concurrency of Javascript which I have noted above but upvoting as your suggestion worked after I'd got my head round the single threading issue.